# multidimensional array skips all values except last one using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two tables: one called `scripts` and hold `script_name` and the called `users` and holds `user_id`, im trying to create multidimensional array that will assign each of the script names to every existing user , for example:  if i have two users `[user_id:1, user_id:2]` and two scripts `[script_id:5,script_id:6]` the array will look something like :

```
[
 (user_id:1,script_id:5),
 (user_id:1,script_id:6),
 (user_id:2,script_id:5),
 (user_id:2,script_id:6)
]
```

the problem is that the array im creating holds only the last user (user 2) and in it all scripts as i want:

```
[
 (user_id:2,script_id:5),
 (user_id:2,script_id:6)
]
```

this is my code:

```
//Create an array
$json_response = array();

//get all users
$usersResult = mysql_query("select user_id from users");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($usersResult, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
    }

//get all script name's and cron format's
$scriptsResult = mysql_query("select script_name from scripts");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($scriptsResult, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['script_name'] = $row['script_name'];
        array_push($json_response,$row_array);
    }
echo json_encode($json_response);
```

Comment: Every `while` iteration overwrites `$row_array[KEY]` value in usersResult `while` loop. What did you expect?

Comment: i tried to add [index++] before ['user_id'] but it didnt solve my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just joining the two tables you don't need two queries, just do:

```
$json_response = array();

$results= mysql_query("select user_id,script_name from users,scripts");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   array_push($json_response,$row);
}
```

Comment: thanks for such a clean solution, if i will try to get another value from scripts (cron_format), dows it work the same with just adding it to the query?

Comment: Yes, you're just performing an outer join on the two tables, you can include as many columns in the results as you want.